# RDS Endpoint is always mapping to external IP

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, rds

I have an RDS instance running and it's internet accessible.

I would like for instances within the VPC to connect to it internally instead of through the internet.

According to another question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089582/amazon-rds-endpoint-internal) the host connect string should map to an internal IP if queried from inside the VPC. This is not working, I'm getting the external IP no matter what.

- I only have one VPC, so there is no peering being used.
- I do have a custom DHCP options set, this is likely where my problem is.

My VPC's DHCP option set is 
`domain-name = mysite.local;domain-name-servers = 10.10.51.254;`

I have a feeling this is where it's broken, due to my custom DHCP option set. `mysite.local` is the local domain, and `10.10.51.254` is a local Bind server (not using Route53).

Do I need to configure some sort of forward lookup on `us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` in my DNS server or is there some piece of configuration I'm missing somewhere? I thought this was supposed to be "automatic" within the VPC so I guess I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem here is indeed that I'm using a private DNS server and not Amazon provided DNS. There isn't any "auto VPC magic from Amazon" going on that helps the domain lookup happen for these AWS services (which I was kind of incorrectly assuming)

> The secret here is that even if you don't use Amazon Provided DNS, you can do lookups against the VPC's DNS server.

If the VPC has `DNS resolution` and `DNS hostnames` set to **`YES`** then you can do a lookup on the VPC's DNS server that is at the base address of the VPC CIDR blocks +2 (so if your VPC is `10.10.0.0/16` then the DNS lookup address is `10.10.0.2`) - I found this off of some random blog post when I was looking this up, not certain if it's in official documentation as all the DNS searches I do through Amazon docs are flooded with Route 53 stuff.

So now that we have a working DNS forward lookup all we need to do is add the forwarding lookup in the bind server. The catch here is that the hostname of the RDS instance is actually a CNAME lookup.

For example:

```
user@host:~$ nslookup mydb.cvxj3uli9kc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Server:     10.10.51.254
Address:    10.10.51.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mydb.cvxj3uli9kc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com    canonical name = ec2-34-204-131-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Name:   ec2-34-204-141-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 34.204.131.19
```

The lookup is actually a CNAME record to a `compute-1.amazonaws.com` so therefore a forward rule is required for BOTH.

**TL;DR:** Given that my VPC's CIDR is `10.10.0.0/16`, here is example forward blocks that solved my problem and answered this question:

```
zone "mydb.cvxj3uli9kc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.10.0.2; };
};

zone "compute-1.amazonaws.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.10.0.2; };
};
```

Now all services in the local VPC can lookup the private IP of the RDS instance, and public resolution also still works from outside the VPC.

Comment: What are you using as a default forwarder for bind? I’m wondering why you are going through all the trouble of setting up multiple individual forwarders for specific hostnames when you can just forward all requests to the internal (10.10.0.2) address. That’s how this is supposed to be done anyways and is almost universally how it is done. It’s faster and more reliable. All I can figure is that you are using root hints or forwarding to some other external DNS server for some reason - but it is most likely wrong to be doing so. That is why you have the issue in the first place.

Comment: Agree with @Appleoddity's assessment, but would also note that if for some reason you really do need your own resolver, then using the VPC-provided resolver at 169.254.169.253 would be more portable across deployments rather than CIDR base + 2, since that one is always the same.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: @Appleoddity That was the first thing I tried and I could resolve the `rds.amazonaws.com` and `compute-1.amazonaws.com` but global internet name resolution wasn't working by using `10.0.0.2` as the default forwarder. If you have any ideas on why, I would definitely go down that route. Also you mentioned "That’s how this is supposed to be done" and I would love to see documentation around that since all the DNS docs I could find from Amazon was just pushing route53. Would sure be simpler if it was working using it as the default forwarder